# angular 2 server side rendering

Tags: angular, typescript, seo, server-side-rendering

https://angular.io/guide/universal

I do all this steps and server-side-rendering works perfect on localhost

I upload project on hosting and server-side-rendering does not work, here I need your help.

Comment: More information would be appreciated. Error log from console ie.

Comment: no errors, think I need to run 
npm run serve:universal on my hosting, but I don't know how

Comment: What is your hosting?

Comment: https://www.youlook.ge/page/unix-hosting

windows hosting

Comment: I assume you have VPS with Windows installed, am I right? As you wrote previous, you need to launch nodeJS on your hosting, to make Universal running.